# Get product using SKU with respect to the store data using Magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento2, product, multistore, rest-api, sku

I use the core API **/V1/products/:sku** to get the product using the SKU.

for example, I have 2 stores, one in English and another in Japanese.
My API Endpoint is like
**http://local.mystore.com/storefront/en-us/rest/V1/products/myproduct** for the English store and
**http://local.mystore.com/storefront/en-jp/rest/V1/products/myproduct** for the Japanese.

For both the API I am getting the same labels (in English) for the attributes but In my Admin I have different labels for the attribute in the store scope level and its works fine in the Magento pages but not in the API.

[image]
In this Function get() the **$storeId** is always null, I guess the problem is in this, if so please let me know How to send the store Id in this API to fix this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your question, you are using the same store code(en-us) for both the mentioned endpoints or stores.

You have to replace the store code from English(en-us) with the Japanese store code(for example en-jp).

After replacing with the Japanese store code it looks like the below.

```
http://local.mystore.com/storefront/en-jp/rest/V1/products/myproduct
```

Now you have to call the store-wise API endpoint as below.

**A] English store journey:** If the customer doing a journey on English Store then call the below endpoint.

```
http://local.mystore.com/storefront/en-us/rest/V1/products/myproduct
```

**A] Japanese store journey:** If the customer doing a journey on a Japanese Store then call the below endpoint. Please note that replace the below store code with the actual your Japanese store code.

http://local.mystore.com/storefront/en-jp/rest/V1/products/myproduct

Check the below Magento Official Reference document showing usage of store code.
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the wrong info, I’ve used the en-jp only at the code level, and while raising the question I typed the wrong endpoint. Now I've updated the question

Comment: Hey! FYI, I have multiple stores in our project & the below APIs giving store-wise results. for example UAE en : /rest/uae_en/V1/products/207360311 & UAE ar : /rest/uae_ar/V1/products/207360311. In my case, I have verified the product name in English & Arabic. Also, I have observed in your endpoints store code before the rest keyword.

Comment: I have doubts about whether you are passing <store_code> in the endpoint or not. Because i assume that this is your domain name for Japanese store  http://local.mystore.com/storefront/en-jp/ right ?

Comment: For a better understanding see this example: /rest/<store_code>/V1/products/<SKU>. In my case uae_en & uae_ar is <store_code>. I hope these findings help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

1)create a xml file at path /app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/webapi.xml

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
<route url="/V1/product/:sku" method="GET">
        <service class="VendorName\ModuleName\Api\ProductsInterface" method="getAdditional"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

2)create app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="VendorName\ModuleName\Api\ProductsInterface" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Products" />  
</config>
```

3)create app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Api/ProductsInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Api;

interface ProductsInterface
{
     /**
     * Get info about product by product SKU
     *
     * @param string $sku
     * @param bool $editMode
     * @param int|null $storeId
     * @param bool $forceReload
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getAdditional($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false);
}
```

4)create app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model/Products.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

class Products implements \Ewall\Mobileshop\Api\ProductsInterface
{
   /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var Product[]
     */
    protected $instances = [];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
     */
    protected $resourceModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $helperFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
     */
    protected $appEmulation;

    /**
     * Review model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory
     */
    protected $_reviewFactory;

     /**
     * Review resource model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_reviewsColFactory;

    /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $priceCurrency;

    /**
     * ProductRepository constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $resourceModel
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param  \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory
     * @param  \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $resourceModel,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $appEmulation,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory $helperFactory,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
    ) {
        $this->productFactory       =  $productFactory;
        $this->storeManager         =  $storeManager;
        $this->resourceModel        =  $resourceModel;
        $this->helperFactory        =  $helperFactory;
        $this->appEmulation         =  $appEmulation;
        $this->_reviewFactory       =  $reviewFactory;
        $this->_reviewsColFactory   =  $collectionFactory;
        $this->priceCurrency        =  $priceCurrency;

    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAdditional($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false)
    {
        $cacheKey = $this->getCacheKey([$editMode, $storeId]);
        if (!isset($this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey]) || $forceReload) {
            $product = $this->productFactory->create();

            $productId = $this->resourceModel->getIdBySku($sku);

            if (!$productId) {

                throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Requested product doesn\'t exist'));
            }
            if ($editMode) {
                $product->setData('_edit_mode', true);
            }
            if ($storeId !== null) {
                $product->setData('store_id', $storeId);
            } else {

                $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            }
            $product->load($productId);

            //Custom Attributes Data Added here            
            $moreInformation = $this->getMoreInformation($product);                     
            $product->setCustomAttribute('more_information', $moreInformation);
            // Custom Attributes Data Ends here
            $this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey] = $product;
            $this->instancesById[$product->getId()][$cacheKey] = $product;          
        }

        return $this->instancesById[$product->getId()][$cacheKey];      

   }

    /**
     * Get key for cache
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return string
     */

    protected function getCacheKey($data)
    {
        $serializeData = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {         

            if (is_object($value)) {
                $serializeData[$key] = $value->getId();             
            } else {                
                $serializeData[$key] = $value;              
            }
        }       
        return md5(serialize($serializeData));
    }

    /**
     * Get More information of the product
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return array
    */

    protected function getMoreInformation($product)
    {
        $data = [];
        $excludeAttr = [];
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

                if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                    $value = __('N/A');
                } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
                    $value = __('No');
                } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                    $value = $this->priceCurrency->convertAndFormat($value);
                }

                if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                    $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = [
                        'label' => __($attribute->getStoreLabel()),
                        'value' => $value,
                        'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $data;
}
```

5)Run command bin/magento setup:di:compile

6)In postman execute url BaseUrl/rest/V1/product/SKU-987